# What is a prediction Equation?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I've been doing some linear regression work for my statistics class and I can't find a good definition or explanation of what prediction equation is. Any help please?

Comment: Say you fit a model by R, minitab, SAS, etc., and you get the coefficients $\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_{p-1}$. The fitted model, or prediction equation, is precisely, $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\cdots+\beta_{p-1}x_{p-1}$.

Comment: @BernardPan And how do I fit that model in R?

Comment: Use function lm(). See http://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/linear-regression-in-r/ for examples.